# get back PHP variable from php CSS file

Tags: php, css, variables

My problem is that I cannot access a PHP variable from a CSS file loaded like this from index.php:

```
<link href="css/style.php" rel="stylesheet">
```

In the style.php file, I have this:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$myClassName = 'myClass'; ?>

.<?= $myClassName?> {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

in my index.php I have this:

```
<span class='<?= $myClassName?>'>this is a text</span>
```

But **$myClassName** return an empty string like it doesn exists...it does mean that I cannot access the PHP variable like this....is there someone have maybe a trick..?

I really need to set the css classnames with PHP variables **from the css file** and be able to **get them back** to my index.php

Comment: To be able to use PHP-variables in other files, you need to use include, require or require_once. Putting it like you do in the style, it will be a separate request to the server and there off totally sandboxed from each other.

Comment: why you don't use include('css/style.php') some thing like that

Answer (score 1):

Under the header, do `$css = $_GET['css'];` or replace it with wherever you are initializing the variable from.For example:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/css'); 
    $css = $_GET['css']; 
?>
body {
    <?= $css ?>border-radius: 3px
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want to pass those data through GET or POST variables.

Comment: @user7566909 _"I don't want to..."_... could you elaborate on why not?